# Using transduce in JavaScript for optimisation - Transducers and Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Any ideas how can I use [transduce](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#transduce) from Ramda.js to make it work without intermediate transformations on data ((2x filtering, 1x sorting)) for optimisation.

```
import { curry, tap, pipe, filter, propEq, sortBy, prop } from 'ramda'

//const debugLog = curry((prefix, data) => console.log('@', prefix, data))

const func = (data, name) =>
  pipe(

    //tap(debugLog('pipe')),

    prop('tasks'),

    //tap(debugLog('prop')),

    filter(propEq('username', name)),
    filter(propEq('complete', false)),
    sortBy(prop('dueDate'))
  )(data)

export default func
```

For now I found something like that, but still I have problems with implementing it to my solution.

```
var numbers = R.range(0, 1000000)
var transducer = R.pipe(
  R.map(R.add(1)),
  R.map(R.multiply(2)),
  R.filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
)

R.transduce(transducer, R.add, [], numbers)
```

Comment: I don't believe sortBy can be used in a transducer (the docs tend to add "Acts as a transducer if a transformer is given in list position." for the functions that can.) Otherwise, easiest way to remove the intermediate data structure between the two filters is just to combine the predicate -> filter(both(propEq('username', name), propEq('complete', false))

Comment: Agreed.  transducers allow you to combine operations on individual elements, but sorting operates over a larger data structure.  It's not as though you can sort the first one then sort the second, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const func = (data, name) =>
    R.sortBy(R.prop('dueDate'), R.transduce( R.compose(
             R.filter(R.propEq('username', name)),
             R.filter(R.propEq('complete', false))
          ), R.flip(R.append), [], data.tasks))
```